# Characteristics and solution of the differential equation $u_t+x^2u_x=u$ by direct substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

The exercise is as follows:
Find and show in the plane (x, y) characteristics of the following equation:

$$u_t+x^2u_x=u$$

Get the general solution and check for direct replacement.

I was able to calculate the general equation, but I can not show the characteristics in the plane (x, y) and do not know how to do the direct substitution.

My calculations:
[image]

Comment: Just an example like than your equation. I've forgotten this method to get the solution, and I hope that the other users can help you, good luck. You can read *Example 7* from this Lecture Notes of [Standford](https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220a/lecturenotes.html). I say the PDF File *First Order-Equations*, to know how solve the author of the lecture notes this kind of problems.

Comment: @user243301 But in my case the problem is different. I do not have initial conditions.

Comment: I forgot this theory, thus was only different example . My apologizes. Now there is an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's find the general solution to:

$$
u_t+x^2u_x=u.
$$
This means characteristic ordinary differential equations are given by: 
$$
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial s}(r,s) &= 1, \\ 
\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s}(r,s) &= x^2, \\ 
\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial s}(r,s) &= z. \\ 
\end{align*}
$$
Solving for each one, we have 
$$
\begin{align*}
dt=ds &\implies t=s+c_1(r),  \\ 
\frac{dx}{x^2}=ds &\implies  -\frac{1}{x}=s+c_2(r), \\ 
\frac{dz}{z}=ds &\implies \ln z = s+c_3(r) \implies z(r,s)= C_3(r)e^{s},\mbox{ where } C_3(r) = e^{c_3(r)}.  \\ 
\end{align*}
$$
Since $s=t-c_1(r)$, we see that $-\frac{1}{x}=t-c_1(r)+c_2(r)$, or $\boxed{t=-\frac{1}{x}+x_0(r)}$, where $x_0(r)=c_1(r)-c_2(r)$.

So the general solution is 
$$
\begin{align*}
z(r,s) &=u(x(r,s),t(r,s)) \\
&=u\left(x,-\frac{1}{x}+x_0(r) \right) \\ 
&=C_3(r) e^{-\frac{1}{x}-c_2(r)} \\ 
&= D(r)e^{-\frac{1}{x}+x_0(r)}, \mbox{ where }D(r)=C_3(r)e^{-c_1(r)}, \\ 
\end{align*}
$$
and one could easily check that $\boxed{u\left(x, -\frac{1}{x}+x_0(r) \right) = D(r)e^{-1/x+x_0(r)}}$ satisfies 
$$
u_t+x^2u_x=u.
$$

Finally, the characteristic curves on the $(x,t)$-plane are $t=-\frac{1}{x}+x_0(r)$.